# Getting system exit error while modelling test data

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

Code:-

```
import sys
from gensim import utils
from gensim.models.doc2vec import LabeledSentence
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = Doc2Vec.load('sentiment140.d2v')

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print ("Please input train_pos_count, train_neg_count and classifier!")
    sys.exit()

train_pos_count = int(sys.argv[1])
train_neg_count = int(sys.argv[2])
test_pos_count = 144
test_neg_count = 144

print (train_pos_count)
print (train_neg_count)

vec_dim = 100

print ("Build training data set...")
train_arrays = numpy.zeros((train_pos_count + train_neg_count, vec_dim))
train_labels = numpy.zeros(train_pos_count + train_neg_count)

for i in range(train_pos_count):
    prefix_train_pos = 'TRAIN_POS_' + str(i)
    train_arrays[i] = model.docvecs[prefix_train_pos]
    train_labels[i] = 1

for i in range(train_neg_count):
    prefix_train_neg = 'TRAIN_NEG_' + str(i)
    train_arrays[train_pos_count + i] = model.docvecs[prefix_train_neg]
    train_labels[train_pos_count + i] = 0


print ("Build testing data set...")
test_arrays = numpy.zeros((test_pos_count + test_neg_count, vec_dim))
test_labels = numpy.zeros(test_pos_count + test_neg_count)

for i in range(test_pos_count):
    prefix_test_pos = 'TEST_POS_' + str(i)
    test_arrays[i] = model.docvecs[prefix_test_pos]
    test_labels[i] = 1

for i in range(test_neg_count):
    prefix_test_neg = 'TEST_NEG_' + str(i)
    test_arrays[test_pos_count + i] = model.docvecs[prefix_test_neg]
    test_labels[test_pos_count + i] = 0


print ("Begin classification...")
classifier = None
if sys.argv[3] == '-lr':
    print ("Logistic Regressions is used...")
    classifier = LogisticRegression()
elif sys.argv[3] == '-svm':
    print ("Support Vector Machine is used...")
    classifier = SVC()
elif sys.argv[3] == '-knn':
    print ("K-Nearest Neighbors is used...")
    classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)
elif sys.argv[3] == '-rf':
    print ("Random Forest is used...")
    classifier = RandomForestClassifier()

classifier.fit(train_arrays, train_labels)

print ("Accuracy:", classifier.score(test_arrays, test_labels))
```

Getting the below error:-
2017-06-08 15:24:18,013 : INFO : loading Doc2Vec object from C:/Users/Desktop/sentiment140.d2v
2017-06-08 15:24:21,556 : INFO : loading wv recursively from C:/Users/Desktop/sentiment140.d2v.wv.* with mmap=None
2017-06-08 15:24:21,556 : INFO : setting ignored attribute syn0norm to None
2017-06-08 15:24:21,571 : INFO : loading docvecs recursively from C:/Users/Desktop/sentiment140.d2v.docvecs.* with mmap=None
2017-06-08 15:24:21,571 : INFO : setting ignored attribute cum_table to None
2017-06-08 15:24:21,571 : INFO : loaded C:/Users/Desktop/sentiment140.d2v
Please input train_pos_count, train_neg_count and classifier!
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2889: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit

Comment: It's hard to read your unformatted logged output. What happens if you "use %tb to see the full traceback" as suggested in the warning text?

Comment: This problem is resolved. Thanks for your reply